# User is not allowed to see the application.: The user is not allowed to see this application per the developer set configuration

Tags: ios, facebook

I have submitted my app to the App Store. I have Facebook login feature in my app. When I try to login to Facebook from devices I have I am able to do it seamlessly.

However Apple has rejected my app saying "Tap Sign in with Facebook with demo account Error message displays ,where we receive a message that states : User is not allowed to see the application.: The user is not allowed to see this application per the developer set configuration."

Not sure how will I be able recreate this issue. I installed my app on 3 different devices and was able to login without any errors. I checked my app setting on Facebook Status and Review section of Facebook and I have enabled my general public. Not sure what else I am missing. I just feel very dejected. Can anyone please help me figure this out? Thank you very much!

Comment: You can put a beta version on the iTunes connect and check, may be the issue is with production version. Maybe with keys or something

Comment: possible duplicate of [The user is not allowed to see this application per the developer set configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395021/the-user-is-not-allowed-to-see-this-application-per-the-developer-set-configurat)