# The user is not allowed to see this application per the developer set configuration

Tags: ios, facebook, ipad

I have submitted my app to the App Store. I have Facebook login feature in my app. When I try to login to Facebook from devices I have I am able to do it seamlessly.

However Apple has rejected my app saying "Tap Sign in with Facebook with demo account Error message displays ,where we receive a message that states : User is not allowed to see the application.: The user is not allowed to see this application per the developer set configuration."

Not sure how will I be able recreate this issue. I installed my app on 3 different devices and was able to login without any errors. I checked my app setting on Facebook Status and Review section of Facebook and I have enabled my general public. Not sure what else I am missing. I just feel very dejected. Can anyone please help me figure this out? Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you copy everything from here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960053/facebook-login-error-user-is-not-allowed-to-see-the-application

Comment: Yes Suresh, for me too same issue my app got rejected twice due to this issue , I am able to login in my iPads , but in apple review they are getting issue , do u have any idea ? Thanks

Comment: those answers aren't works for you. right? The message is related to the facebook authentication. Is there anything like "Move to Production" in your facebook developer account? Sand box mode ON?

Comment: yes Suresh, those aren't working for me, No option like "Move to Production", there is option like make available to public and i marked it as Yes , I tested with itunes after review of testflight beta , even then it happens with apple production. do uyou have any idea?, Thanks

Comment: This might be the source of your trouble: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26788622/1055722